# Infinite Grid only 1 column Issues

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Siby/37q4N/2/) is the JS fiddle where I just copy pasted the sample example given by ExtJS and Kept only 1 column and that too locked. In this scenario we have 2 errors :

1. Its making continuous calls to backend till it gets last result. We
   can check in fiddler that the calls are getting posted to backend
   continously till the last page.

   1. I am not able to scroll(vertical) in grid

Is it bug from ExtJS 4.2.1 Infinite Grid ? is there a solution ?
If we add 1 more column unlocked then its working fine (It will make only 1 request to backend and on scroll it will make next request depending on the scroller position)

Below is the same code :

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define('ForumThread', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'title', 'forumtitle', 'forumid', 'username', {
            name: 'replycount',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'lastpost',
            mapping: 'lastpost',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'timestamp'
        },
            'lastposter', ' ', 'threadid']
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'store',
        model: 'ForumThread',
        //remoteGroup: true,
        // allow the grid to interact with the paging scroller by buffering
        buffered: true,
        leadingBufferZone: 300,
        pageSize: 50,
        proxy: {
            // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
            // this page, an Ajax proxy would be better
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/remote_topics/index.php',
            reader: {
                root: 'topics',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            // This particular service cannot sort on more than one field, so if grouped, disable sorting
            beforeprefetch: function (store, operation) {}
        }
    });
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'ExtJS.com - Browse Forums',
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        // grid columns
        columns: [{
            id: 'last',
            text: "Last Post",
            locked: true,
            dataIndex: 'lastpost',
            width: 130,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('n/j/Y g:i A'),
            sortable: true,
            groupable: false
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```